# How do I manage the state of a dynamic sidebar with animations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, sidebar

I am fairly new to React and struggling with implementing a sidebar that is dynamic to each page and has animations that shouldn't stop the navigation of the app's core content.

Below is the root of the app.

```
<Router>
    <div className="app-container">

      <LeftSidebar sidebarState={ this.state.sidebar.left } />
      <RightSidebar sidebarState={ this.state.sidebar.right } />

      <div
        style={{
          marginLeft: (this.state.sidebar.left.open ? this.state.sidebar.left.width : 0),
          marginRight: (this.state.sidebar.right.open ? this.state.sidebar.right.width : 0)
        }}
        className='app-content'>
        <Toolbar toggleSidebar={ this.toggleSidebar } />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ Dashboard } />
          <Redirect from="/dashboard" to="/" />
          <Route path="/gear" render={ (props) => <Gear {...props} toggleSidebar={ this.toggleSidebar } /> } />
          <Route component={ PageNotFound } />
        </Switch>
      </div>

    </div>
  </Router>
```

1. Sidebars at the top, absolute positioned left and right. (These are set to translate -100% and 100% to animate in and out, with an app-content moving margin with the same transition)
2. The `app-content` div contains the main content, which is the active component.

I'm working on the `/gear` component and I'm adding a sidebar to edit an item, though I'd like to have the sidebar available since I will more than likely use it in the other views.

To try and solve this problem I made a new component for gear sidebar (and would make other sidebar components as needed) and moved it into the gear component which then used a portal to move it to the body so it would style correctly. Then I'd toggle it by passing a toggleSidebar function which just flips a boolean in the state for the given side. This kinda worked but when navigating between pages I tried to have a ReactCSSTransitionGroup but I don't want to main content to wait for the timeout since it can happen as the new component is loaded.

So since I need the sidebar to be loaded and animating closing if open while the component it's connected to is unmounting, it'd only make sense to move it to the parent.

The only problem is, how do I load a dynamically passed component in the sidebar, then easier to solve wait for a timeout before its loaded so the animation can occur.

I was thinking of passing a function to the component that is being navigated to which can be executed to pass a component to render in the sidebar. It'd need to be a component since it will need still need to have methods etc. attached to it.

Otherwise, I thought using a router might work, but I'm not sure if you can timeout (if open) when they are unmounted to prevent it being moved to the other route.

Finally, the only way I get it to work at the moment is if I verbosely define sidebars and mount them dependent on the route, basically making a custom react-router.

Really struggling with this, any helps appreciated.